# filtering an array inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter

I have an array that looks something like this

```
var categorizedBooks = [
{
 name: "category1",
 books:[
        {name:"book1", bookContainerId: 1, active: true},
        {name:"book2", bookContainerId: 2, active: false},
        {name:"book3", bookContainerId: 2, active: true},
       ]
 },
{
 name: "category2",
 books:[
        {name:"book4", bookContainerId: 1, active: false},
        {name:"book5", bookContainerId: 3, active: true},
        {name:"book6", bookContainerId: 4, active: true},
       ]
 },
{
 name: "category3",
 books:[
        {name:"book7", bookContainerId: 1, active: false},
        {name:"book8", bookContainerId: 2, active: true},
        {name:"book9", bookContainerId: 4, active: false},
       ]
 },
{
 name: "category4",
 books:[
        {name:"book10", bookContainerId: 2, active: false},
        {name:"book11", bookContainerId: 2, active: false},
        {name:"book12", bookContainerId: 4, active: false},
       ]
 }
```

And i want to filter them on two arrays that looks something like this:

```
bookContainers: [1,3]
isActive: ['active', 'inactive] // an array of strings
```

These comes from inputs so it can change whenever. So i want to match bookContainers with their bookContainerId, and 'active'/'inactive' string array with their boolean active property and if a an object in categorizedBooks books array is empty i want to remove it.

So in this case i would get something like this (Desired output from the above):

```
{
 name: "category1",
 books:[
        {name:"book1", bookContainerId: 1, active: true}
       ]
 },
{
 name: "category2",
 books:[
        {name:"book4", bookContainerId: 1, active: false},
        {name:"book5", bookContainerId: 3, active: true}
       ]
 },
{
 name: "category3",
 books:[
        {name:"book7", bookContainerId: 1, active: false}
       ]
 }
```

Another problem is that i don't want to modify the original array because i want to be able to call it with new arrays to filter on whenever, and get the result.
Here is my GET method now:

```
public get bookCategories(): Array<CategorizedBook> {
    let cloneToMapOf = [...this.categoriesAndBooks];

    const filteredCategories = cloneToMapOf.map(categorizedbooks => {
        categorizedbooks.books = categorizedbooks.properties.filter(book =>{
            return (rc.includes(books.bookContainerId) && 
sa.includes(book.active ? 'active' : 'inactive'));
        });
        return categorizedbooks;
    });

    const result = filteredCategories.filter(x => x.books.length > 0 && x.books != null);
    return result;
}
```

But for some reason this code modifies this.categoriesAndBooks so I becomes empty after time..

with the result I want to present in some HTML

```
    <nz-collapse [nzBordered]="false" *ngFor="let categorizedBook of bookCategories;">
        <nz-collapse-panel [nzHeader]="categorizedBook.name" [nzActive]="true">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let book of categorizedBook.properties; trackBy:trackBy.book">
                <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="bookEditors" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{book: book, form: bookValueForm}"></ng-template>
            </ng-container>
        </nz-collapse-panel>
    </nz-collapse>
```

I've been sitting with this for hours.. please help me

Comment: I did not understand the 'active' inactive part, can you explain it better ?

Comment: this is not clear could you please put the desired output and what did you tried

Comment: It's basically an array of strings that need to match the boolean true => 'active'

Comment: @G.aziz The desired output is there, i can add what I've tried.

Comment: @LittleMygler edit your and add th output you want to get from this obeject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update

```
const filteredCategories = cloneToMapOf.map(categorizedbooks => {
        const books = categorizedbooks.properties.filter(book =>{
            return (rc.includes(books.bookContainerId) && 
sa.includes(book.active ? 'active' : 'inactive'));
        });
        return {...categorizedbooks,books}; // so that original array is not mutated.
    });
```

I have created a inner filter for books that are part of the container AND active state is one of the states in active array and then an outer filter for categories with empty book array

```js
var categorizedBooks = [
{
 name: "category1",
 books:[
        {name:"book1", bookContainerId: 1, active: true},
        {name:"book2", bookContainerId: 2, active: false},
        {name:"book3", bookContainerId: 2, active: true},
       ]
 },
{
 name: "category2",
 books:[
        {name:"book4", bookContainerId: 1, active: false},
        {name:"book5", bookContainerId: 3, active: true},
        {name:"book6", bookContainerId: 4, active: true},
       ]
 },
{
 name: "category3",
 books:[
        {name:"book7", bookContainerId: 1, active: false},
        {name:"book8", bookContainerId: 2, active: true},
        {name:"book9", bookContainerId: 4, active: false},
       ]
 },
{
 name: "category4",
 books:[
        {name:"book10", bookContainerId: 2, active: false},
        {name:"book11", bookContainerId: 2, active: false},
        {name:"book12", bookContainerId: 4, active: false},
       ]
 }
 ];
var bookContainers = [1,3]
var isActive = ['active', 'inactive'];

var isActiveBoolState = isActive.map(state => state === 'active'); // helper to show which type of active state should be showed.

var result = categorizedBooks.map(category => ({...category, books: category.books.filter(book => bookContainers.includes( book.bookContainerId) && isActiveBoolState.includes(book.active)  )})).filter(category => category.books.length);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `state === 'active' ? true : false` is an anti-pattern, use `state === 'active'` instead.

Comment: updated, not sure if it is an anti-pattern though, thought it would be more readable. but it makes sense not to add the obvious

Comment: Problem with this is it makes a recursive thing with my html so it just runs and runs, check update for how i use it :)

Comment: I gets stuck in a recursive get, where the data updates and it fetches it again

Comment: @LittleMygler use the spread operator like I did in my answer. In your answere you are mutating the original object inside the array!

Answer (score 0):

You could take the wanted keys in an array and add the values instead of some semantic values which needs to be converted to data types of the object for testing.

The result is an array with a filtered sub array and reassembled if the sub array contains some elements.

```js
var categorizedBooks = [{ name: "category1", books: [{ name: "book1", bookContainerId: 1, active: true }, { name: "book2", bookContainerId: 2, active: false }, { name: "book3", bookContainerId: 2, active: true }] }, { name: "category2", books: [{ name: "book4", bookContainerId: 1, active: false }, { name: "book5", bookContainerId: 3, active: true }, { name: "book6", bookContainerId: 4, active: true }] }, { name: "category3", books: [{ name: "book7", bookContainerId: 1, active: false }, { name: "book8", bookContainerId: 2, active: true }, { name: "book9", bookContainerId: 4, active: false }] }, { name: "category4", books: [{ name: "book10", bookContainerId: 2, active: false }, { name: "book11", bookContainerId: 2, active: false }, { name: "book12", bookContainerId: 4, active: false }] }],
    filters = [['bookContainerId', [1, 3]], ['active', [true, false]]],
    result = categorizedBooks.reduce((r, { name, books }) => {
        books = books.filter(o => filters.every(([k, v]) => v.includes(o[k])));
        if (books.length) r.push({ name, books });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice code, but this also creates a recursive pattern when added into my *ngIf for some reason